# WPF radial-gradients

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, radial-gradients

I have tried the following code, but the last line causes an error
*Error Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.RadialGradientBrush' to 'System.Drawing.Brush'
*

I have visual studio 2008

```
<CODE>

/*
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows;
*/
        private void Main_Screen_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rBoundingBox = e.ClipRectangle;
            RadialGradientBrush radialGradient = new RadialGradientBrush();
            radialGradient.GradientOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(5, 5);
            radialGradient.Center = new System.Windows.Point(5, 5);
            radialGradient.RadiusX = 5;
            radialGradient.RadiusY = 5;
            radialGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
            radialGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.25));
            radialGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Blue, 0.75));
            radialGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 1.0));
            radialGradient.Freeze();

        rBoundingBox.Inflate(-5, -5);

        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(radialGradient, rBoundingBox);
    }
```

can anyone tell me how to fill an elipse with the radial brush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `void Main_Screen_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)` it is clear that your application is Windows.Forms. The `RadialGradientBrush` however is a WPF component. That's just not compatible.

Personally I think it borders on silly that the WPF namespaces start with `System.Windows`, but such is life.

Comment: Thank you for you replies, please have a look at my latest question.
P.S. the 'WPF' tag was added automatically